.NET Android Mono crash (mono_runtime_invoke_checked, mono_assembly_request_byname)
This appears to happen most frequently in Android 13 then Android 14 and Android 12 much less frequently. I'm not sure what the problem could be, however it appears to have started at the beginning of April. Could it be related to .NET runtime updates? It appears this problem existed before but it was 30 times less frequent.
This is the stack trace from Google Play Console:
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 20507 >>> com.my.app <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000000d770c  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #01  pc 0x00000000000bb2a8  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #02  pc 0x00000000000bd8e4  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #03  pc 0x00000000000c25b0  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #04  pc 0x00000000000c1a1c  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000152194  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000151cf8  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000004300 

Cause: [GWP-ASan]: Buffer Overflow, 11 bytes right of a 16-byte allocation at 0x7685c9bff0

allocated by thread 20507:
  #00  pc 0x00000000000945f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (gwp_asan::AllocationMetadata::CallSiteInfo::RecordBacktrace(unsigned long (*)(unsigned long*, unsigned long))+84)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000094c64  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (gwp_asan::GuardedPoolAllocator::allocate(unsigned long, unsigned long)+600)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000050b14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so ((anonymous namespace)::gwp_asan_calloc(unsigned long, unsigned long)+192)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000051570  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (calloc+148)
  #04  pc 0x00000000001d6d94  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000253dc4  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000201f00  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000201ccc  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #08  pc 0x00000000002020cc  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_class_inflate_generic_type_checked+44) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #09  pc 0x000000000023afb8  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #10  pc 0x000000000023c994  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_method_signature_checked_slow+312) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #11  pc 0x000000000023cc50  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_method_signature_internal_slow+40) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #12  pc 0x00000000000df750  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #13  pc 0x00000000000bb2a8  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #14  pc 0x00000000000bd8e4  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #15  pc 0x00000000000c25b0  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #16  pc 0x00000000000c1a1c  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #17  pc 0x0000000000152194  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #18  pc 0x0000000000151cf8  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #19  pc 0x0000000000004300 
  #20  pc 0x00000000000046d0 
  #21  pc 0x000000000001f404 
  #22  pc 0x000000000001f314 
  #23  pc 0x000000000001b90c 
  #24  pc 0x000000000002e980 
  #25  pc 0x000000000002eaac 
  #26  pc 0x00000000000c6708  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #27  pc 0x000000000025f760  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_runtime_try_invoke+148) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #28  pc 0x000000000026296c  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_runtime_try_invoke_handle+40) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #29  pc 0x0000000000295208  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #30  pc 0x0000000000294d28  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #31  pc 0x00000000001fbcfc  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_assembly_request_byname+1088) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #32  pc 0x00000000001f9768  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #33  pc 0x000000000022b3a0  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #34  pc 0x000000000002e56c 
  #35  pc 0x000000000002a130 
  #36  pc 0x0000000000026498 
  #37  pc 0x0000000000026204 
  #38  pc 0x0000000000025d58 
  #39  pc 0x00000000000254c4 
  #40  pc 0x0000000000024eec 
  #41  pc 0x000000000003e990 
  #42  pc 0x00000000000369ec 
  #43  pc 0x0000000000035f80 
  #44  pc 0x0000000000035de4 
  #45  pc 0x0000000000035acc 
  #46  pc 0x0000000000035860 
  #47  pc 0x0000000000035558 
  #48  pc 0x0000000000034e14 
  #49  pc 0x0000000000034d5c 
  #50  pc 0x0000000000034b64 
  #51  pc 0x000000000000c3d0 
  #52  pc 0x000000000000a9a0 
  #53  pc 0x00000000000059f0 
  #54  pc 0x000000000000525c 
  #55  pc 0x00000000000051a4 
  #56  pc 0x000000000001c2f8 
  #57  pc 0x0000000000017344 
  #58  pc 0x0000000000029c3c 
  #59  pc 0x000000000003d4e4 
  #60  pc 0x000000000003d62c 
  #61  pc 0x00000000000c6708  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #62  pc 0x000000000025e6bc  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_runtime_invoke_checked+140) (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #63  pc 0x0000000000266f14  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #64  pc 0x00000000002233dc  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #65  pc 0x000000000022cb34  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 772b5b20680b2bc4ef1437a4b9b0edbfca44e834)
  #66  pc 0x000000000000926c 
  #67  pc 0x000000000000910c 
  #68  pc 0x0000000000008e50 
  #69  pc 0x000000000000b2b8 
  #70  pc 0x000000000000d444 
  #71  pc 0x000000000000c998 
  #72  pc 0x000000000000d61c 
  #73  pc 0x000000000000c650 
  #74  pc 0x000000000000c494 
  #75  pc 0x000000000000b23c 
  #76  pc 0x000000000000aa04 
  #77  pc 0x000000000000a6b4 
  #78  pc 0x000000000000a5d0 
  #79  pc 0x000000000003d164 
  #80  pc 0x000000000003d164 
  #81  pc 0x000000000000a3a0 
  #82  pc 0x000000000000a1bc 
  #83  pc 0x0000000000036368 
  #84  pc 0x000000000000ddec 
  #85  pc 0x0000000000007910 
  #86  pc 0x0000000000007758 
  #87  pc 0x00000000000000ec 
  #88  pc 0x00000000000e0404  /data/app/~~RcYDxouvn53KOiX0Jb2qYQ==/com.my.app-64F8rHq7y0Hp-ej4NHOVdA==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+116)

Any ideas? It appears to be caused by assembly loading, which doesn't narrow it down at all.

This seems to stem from Android Runtime, not the.NET Runtime though, Check if your native Android dependencies depend on Xamarin Android Runtime if yes then try upgrading it

I'm using the .NET for Android flavour, latest versions. I keep almost everything updated. There are a lot of dependencies, half native. I'm going to sift through them again tonight and list maybe them here.

Issues like this require in-depth investigation which usually starts from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues. If you have support contracts with Microsoft then a support case via https://support.microsoft.com might speed it up a bit.
